# How can I test for the presence of an Action Filter with constructor arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to test that my base controller is decorated with a certain action filter. Because this filter's constructor looks to `web.config`, my first try at testing fails because the test project doesn't have a valid config file. Moving on, I used a `TestConfigProvider` that I inject into the filter constructor, but the following test fails because the config provider isn't passed to the constructor. How else can I test if this filter is applied?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Base_controller_must_have_MaxLengthFilter_attribute()
{
    var att = typeof(BaseController).GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthFilter>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(att);
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, you have taken a good first step by recognizing that Web.config is just another dependency and wrapping it into a ConfigProvider to inject is an excellent solution.

But, you are getting tripped up on one of the design problems of MVC - namely, that to be DI-friendly, attributes should only provide meta-data, but [never actually define behavior](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/). This isn't an issue with your approach to testing, it is an issue with the approach to the design of the filter.

As pointed out in the post, you can get around this issue by splitting your action filter attribute into 2 parts.

1. An attribute that contains no behavior to flag your controllers and action methods with.
2. A DI-friendly class that implements [IActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter(v=vs.100).aspx) and contains the desired behavior.

The approach is to use the IActionFilter to test for the presence of the attribute, and then execute the desired behavior. The action filter can be supplied with all dependencies and then injected when the application is composed.

```
IConfigProvider provider = new WebConfigProvider();
IActionFilter filter = new MaxLengthActionFilter(provider);
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(filter);
```

> **NOTE:** If you need any of the filter's dependencies to have a lifetime shorter than singleton, you will need to use a `GlobalFilterProvider` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221865/questions-about-using-ninject/36224308#36224308).

The implementation of MaxLengthActionFilter would look something like this:

```
public class MaxLengthActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public readonly IConfigProvider configProvider;

    public MaxLengthActionFilter(IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        if (configProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("configProvider");
        this.configProvider = configProvider;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var attribute = this.GetMaxLengthAttribute(filterContext.ActionDescriptor);
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            var maxLength = attribute.MaxLength;

            // Execute your behavior here, and use the configProvider as needed
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var attribute = this.GetMaxLengthAttribute(filterContext.ActionDescriptor);
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            var maxLength = attribute.MaxLength;

            // Execute your behavior here, and use the configProvider as needed
        }
    }

    public MaxLengthAttribute GetMaxLengthAttribute(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        MaxLengthAttribute result = null;

        // Check if the attribute exists on the controller
        result = (MaxLengthAttribute)actionDescriptor
            .ControllerDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        // NOTE: You might need some additional logic to determine 
        // which attribute applies (or both apply)

        // Check if the attribute exists on the action method
        result = (MaxLengthAttribute)actionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
}
```

And, your attribute *which should not contain any behavior* should look something like this:

```
// This attribute should contain no behavior. No behavior, nothing needs to be injected.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MaxLengthAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MaxLengthAttribute(int maxLength)
    {
        this.MaxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public int MaxLength { get; private set; }
}
```

With a more loosely coupled design, testing for the existence of the attribute is much more straightforward.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Base_controller_must_have_MaxLengthFilter_attribute()
{
    var att = typeof(BaseController).GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(att);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @NightOwl888! This is indeed an answer I can sink my teeth into - and easy to understand. I have always agreed that attributes shouldn't define behaviour, but my limited time for introspection forced me to make an exception for action filter attributes.

Comment: It seems to me that adding IActionFilter into pipeline has some drawbacks that should be mentioned. It will slightly affect performance as a filter should be executed for each request. Also you should be carefull because any error in action filter will make your service unavailable.

Comment: @PopovSergey - Actually, no not if you design the filter correctly (there is a reason why they are called filters). The purpose of the filter is just for determining *when* to execute the shared behavior, it should not actually execute it. That should be delegated to an handler that derives from `ActionResult` [as Microsoft does in AuthorizeAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L125) by setting `filterContext.Result` if and only if it is required to run.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can add the valid config file to your test project via "add file as link"
[image]
[image]

Comment: Resorting to a dependency on an external config source is only my absolute last option.

Answer (score -2):

Recently I here more and more question regarding config "problems". They all have a common base - you have several projects, servers, services that need to use the same config. My advise to you - stop using Web.config.

Place all your configuration into the database!
Add a table (or maybe several tables) with all your configuration keys an values and read them when the application starts (global.asax).

This way you don't need to worry about coping your config to every project or injecting it to different constructors.

Comment: And how do I make IIS read from my database? The problem here isn't at all with config, but with having no GetCustomAttribute that takes constructor arguments. The whole debate of config is another, separate matter.

Comment: Web.Config is a perfectly acceptable place to store your config values, and is non-complex. You can inject values into classes, and configure them per environment without any hassle.