# How to use MVC custom attribute on aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My application is in Asp.net MVC 4. I'm using .aspx page for opening of report. I've implemented custom user rights attribute on all action of application. I want to use it on my .aspx.cs page class or every function that is in .aspx.cs page. How to use it? can i use MVC custom attribute in aspx page
In mvc I'm using like this

```
[AuthorizeUserControls("urlInventoryReport")]   
public ActionResult Inventory(string ReportTitle)    
{

}
```

How to use in .aspx.cs page

```
public partial class ReportViewer : System.Web.UI.Page

{

[AuthorizeUserControls("urlInventoryReport")] //it's not working

private void ViewInventoryReport()

{

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Attributes are *static* objects that apply metadata to a type in .NET. They contain no *behavior*.

The reason why your attribute works in ASP.NET MVC is because MVC has a *filter* which runs before and after the call to the action method is performed. This filter is called by the MVC framework, which in turn is called by the route handler (a specialized HTTP handler).

The fact that the behavior is defined in the same class as the attribute (yielding an ActionFilterAttribute) is just for convenience. You could just as well separate the attribute from the action filter as is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245220/how-can-i-test-for-the-presence-of-an-action-filter-with-constructor-arguments/27470397#27470397).

Following the MVC approach to make your `IActionFilter` function, would be to use .NET routing for your page and make a specialized `IRouteHandler` that can scan your page object after it is instantiated using Reflection to determine if the attribute exists, and then execute the behavior in the associated `IActionFilter`. I suggest if you go this route, you analyze the [MVC source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and extract the bits that you need, but it is not for the faint of heart.

Alternatively, you could put the scanning implementation into the `Page_Init` event, but at that point you might just be better off not bothering with declaring the attribute statically and just executing the behavior locally.

Assuming your attribute derives from `ActionFilterAttribute`, you could do something like:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var attribute = new AuthorizeUserControls("urlInventoryReport");
    var filterContext = CreateFakeActionExecutingContext(); // TODO: Implement this.
    attribute.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```