# Unity DependencyAttribute works for Controller but not FilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've setup Unity in my WebAPI project and I am getting the objects injected properly when using the `DependencyAttribute` in one of my ApiControllers. I'm now trying to use the exact same approach in an `ActionFilterAttribute`, but it is not resolving (resolves to null).

This resolves to null:

```
public class ValidateEntryAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency]
    internal ApplicationUserManager UserManager { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

where this resolves to an instance of the object:

```
public class LayoutController : BaseApiController
{
    [Dependency]
    internal ApplicationUserManager UserManager { get; set; }
}
```

and my UnityConfig looks like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserStore>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unity can not inject things in attributes, change your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your approach to designing filters to make them [passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) and then use true dependency injection (constructor injection) on action filters that are designed to read them, as shown in [this `IActionFilter` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245220/how-can-i-test-for-the-presence-of-an-action-filter-with-constructor-arguments/27470397#27470397) or in [this `AuthorizeAttribute` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235660/unity-inject-dependencies-into-mvc-filter-class-with-parameters/32254851#32254851).

Alternatively, you could hack the framework as shown [here](http://michael-mckenna.com/blog/dependency-injection-for-asp-net-web-api-action-filters-in-3-easy-steps) to get property injection on action filter attributes. But then you are stuck with property injection and all of the [downsides](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/) that come with it.