# ActionFilter and Authorize Attribute in MVC causing object reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I am using `MVC4` to build `ASP.NET` application. I am using `ActionFilterAttribute` and `AuthorizeAttribute` in my business logic. Following is sample code

**Controller Class**

```
[SessionExpire]
[AuthorizeSubscription]
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult StoreDetail()
    {
       // My logic goes here
    }

    [AuthorizeProductEdit]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditProduct()
    {
       // My logic goes here
    }
```

If we look at the code, I have first used `SessionExpire` attribute that inherit `ActionFilterAttribute` class, It check if `session` is valid for current request and do some redirection there. Next, i am checking `AuthorizeSubscription` attribute that inherit `AuthorizeAttribute` class. It also do some redirection based on logic written over there.

In `EditProduct` Action, i have used another `AuthorizeAttribute`.

If I hit url for `StoreDetail` Action without making any `session`, it redirect me to desired page.

But if i hit url for `EditProduct` Action, It throws me `Object Reference error`. During debug It first goes into the code for `AuthorizeProdcutEdit` and there fail for finding `Session` Null.

Why it is not executing `SessionExpire` code first and exit from there if found `Session` Null ?

Comment: Did you remember to register the Action Filter

Comment: My Question is, why it execute the `AuthorizeProductEdit` code first. Instead it should execute `SessionExpire` code first as it is applied on `controller` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx):

> Filters run in the following order:
>
> 1. Authorization filters
> 2. Action filters
> 3. Response filters
> 4. Exception filters

The reason your `SessionExpire` attribute fires after your `AuthorizeSubscription` attribute is because MVC always fires Authorization filters first.

So to fix that problem, you need your `SessionExpire` to implement `IAuthorizationFilter` (and presumably inherit `Attribute`).

In addition, you will need to [set the order of your attributes](https://blog.rajsoftware.com/2011/05/14/mvc3-filter-ordering/), because the .NET framework does not guarantee which order they will be processed in.

```
[SessionExpire(Order=1)]
[AuthorizeSubscription(Order=2)]
public class StoreController : Controller
{
   // Remaining implementation...
```

Do note that the best approach is to [separate your filters from your attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245220/how-can-i-test-for-the-presence-of-an-action-filter-with-constructor-arguments/27470397#27470397), which both allows them to be DI-friendly and also allows you to set the order explicitly by registering the filters globally in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx), the order of the filtering attributes is first determined by its type (e.g. Authorization filter, Action filter etc.) and then by its scope (e.g. Controller scope, Action scope).

Your `SessionExpire` attribute has type Action, scope Controller.
Your `AuthorizeProductEdit` attribute has type Authorization, scope Action.

This is why your `AuthorizeProductEdit` attribute strikes in first.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) (my emphasis)

> The ASP.NET MVC framework supports four different types of filters:
>
> Authorization filters – Implements the IAuthorizationFilter attribute.
>
> Action filters – Implements the IActionFilter attribute.
>
> Result filters – Implements the IResultFilter attribute.
>
> Exception filters – Implements the IExceptionFilter attribute.
>
> Filters are executed in the order listed above. For example, **authorization filters are always executed before action filters** and exception filters are always executed after every other type of filter.