# Custom authorization filter logs twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a custom authorization filter with some checks in it. When the check fails it is writing to a log file. The strange thing is that with every fail it writes the error text twice to the log. How to make sure it only logs the error once?

```
    public class AuthorizationFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

            var key = “wrong key”;

            if (key != “correct key”)
            {
                DateTime DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp;
                string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Logs\log.txt");

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime + “| error XYZ”);
                }

                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Most likely you have registered your filter twice somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the filter registered globally...

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizationFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

It will fire once when the original action is run. Then it will return 401 unauthorized. This status is caught by ASP.NET and will automatically redirect to the login page. When the login page loads, your filter runs again (and presumably fails again).

To make it stop doing this, there are a couple of options.

1. Inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` instead of `FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter`. Override the `AuthorizeCore` method and return `false` when the login fails. Use the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` attribute on your login method (and any other methods you don't want to check).
2. Build your own logic to either check for `AllowAnonymousAttribute` or a custom attribute. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27470397/181087) of checking for an attribute within a filter.

I suggest you use the first option. The reason is that in addition to automatically gaining the functionality of the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` there is also some code to deal with using output caching in conjunction with authorization.