# Cannot create instance of repository object in action filter MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository

```
public interface IUserRepository : IBaseRepository<user>
{

   user GetUser(int userId);
   user Get(string Email);


}
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<user>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unit) : base(unit)
    {

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public user GetUser(int userId)
    {
        return dbSet.Where(x => x.ID == userId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public user Get(string Email)
    {
        var obj = dbSet.Where(s => s.Email == Email).FirstOrDefault();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And I am using the repository in my controller as below

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager UserManager;
    private readonly ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager;
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;
    private readonly UserRepository userrepo;


    public AccountController(UserRepository _userrepo, ApplicationUserManager userManager,                                 ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,IUnitOfWork _uow)
    {
        this.UserManager = userManager;
        this.SignInManager = signInManager;
        this.AuthenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.uow = _uow;           
        userrepo = _userrepo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid )
        {
         var user = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

         var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

         if (result)            
          { 
            var myUser = userRepo.Get(user.Id);
            if (myUser.SubscriptionStatus == 1)
            {
               return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Manage", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            }
            else
            {
              return RedirectToAction("Index","Admin");
            }   
        }
     }
   }
```

And this is my action filter

```
public class CheckFirstLoginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationUserManager UserManager;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;
    private readonly UserRepository userrepo;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        string uName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uName))
        {                
            //var user = UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(uName);
            //The above & below lines are not creating instance of the UserManager & UserRepository object, it is always null
            user cUser= userrepo.GetUserId(uName);
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Manage",
                action = "ChangePassword"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

And I am using Unity for the dependency injection

```
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    private static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<MyDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<UserRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
        container.RegisterType<HomeController>();
        container.RegisterType<AccessCodeController>();
        container.RegisterType<AdminController>();

        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<MyUser, int>, UserStore<MyUser, MyRole, int, MyUserLogin, MyUserRole, MyUserClaim>>(
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
    }
}
```

How can I create the instance of the repository class and access the Get(string email) method. So that I can check the subscription status from the database.

I tried many ways and always failed to create the instance.

Kindly Help me.

Thanks
Tarak

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27470397/181087), and if your repository needs a lifetime shorter than singleton (which is probably the case), use the mentioned GlobalFilterProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CheckFirstLoginAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);


        string uName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uName))
        {
            //Here is how I could get the instance of the repository
            //I had to register the repository type and then
            //I resolved it to obtain the object of the repository and
            //access the methods in the repository
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            container.RegisterType<UserRepository>();

            UserRepository repo = container.Resolve<UserRepository>();

            user cUser = repo.GetUserId(uName);
            if (cUser.SubscriptionStatus == 1)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Manage",
                    action = "ChangePassword"
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```