# How to set Action Filter in Filter Config with Injections MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I created an ActionFilter and in this filter I Injected services as Constructor Injections.
These services each implement many services themselves.
when I want to set my ActionFilter in `FilterConfig.cs` I got errors. Obviously for Constructor which need services.

```
public class PermissionControlActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    readonly IApplicationUserManager _usermanager;
    readonly IPermissionHelper _permissionhelper;
    public PermissionControlActionFilter(IApplicationUserManager usermanager, IPermissionHelper permissionHelper)
    {
        _usermanager = usermanager;
        _permissionhelper = permissionHelper;
    }...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27470397/3763021) answer to a similar question and I think you'll be able to come right.

The point of the article and answer is that your attribute shouldn't do the work because attributes don't have a constructor valid for DI. A filter on the other hand does and can check for the existence of a specific attribute, and if it is there, then it performs the work.

Comment: Thank you but doesn't  help me. I designed the actionfilter and i think it works but I don't know how can i use with that two interfaces need in constructor? no matter in FilterConfig or top of Controllers or Actions! Thanks. @Topher

Comment: @Rezash can you should the stack trace of the error you get

Comment: Well. it seems this section of project , will done in next version , hopefully there is no need to do this. by the way Thanks for your time. @Topher